# Cancel a .Speak with Microsoft.Speech

Tags: c#, microsoft-speech-platform

I'm having an application that uses Microsoft.Speech for TTS.
I'm having problems with my TTS, if the stream gets d/c'ed before its done.

```
public void SpeakTest()
{
  PromptBuilder prompt = new PromptBuilder();
  prompt.AppendText("This is a test prompt...");
  _speechSynthersizer.Speak(prompt);
  prompt.ClearContent();
}
```

This TTS object can be disposed before the speak is done, which leading to System.IO.EndOfStreamException and System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot change synthesizer's output while speaking. exceptions.

How can I cancel a speak, so when my object is being disposed, it will cancel the speak and dispose the object correctly??

Comment: Can't you just do a check to see if it's disposed?

Comment: That won't solve my problem when there is a speak going on currently while disposing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to use *asynchronous* version of *Speak* method i.e. *SpeakAsync*  and try to cancel  an asynchronous speak operation, before disposing TTS object, by using one of the following methods: *SpeakAsyncCancel* or *SpeakAsyncCancelAll*. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakasynccancelall(v=vs.110).aspx) you can find an example.

Comment: The only problem with using the Async method is, that it will result in playing my speak at same time as with the waiting music playing in another channel. Any smart solutions on this, so there ain't more than one channel speaking at a time??

Comment: You can write a wrapper around SpeechSynthesizer class which will queue requests and will start speaking only if a previous speech is over. You can detect completeness of speaking by subscribing SpeakCompleted event.

Comment: Hmm... Might be possible to use the Complete event to do the task. The case is, that the stream can be ended by remote point, which means that even tho I'm waiting with diposing the object until speak is finished, it will possible throw the EndOfStream exception. The best way will be to cancel any speak going on, when the remote point has ended the stream. Is this only possible with Async speak? And if it is, then I guess I have to create some wait handle while playing speak, and AsyncCancelAll when disposing??

Comment: Found a fix for this. I changed my SetOutputToAudioStream to my SpeechSythesisConnector instead of SpeechSynthesisConnector.Stream, and removed the code in my dispose method, which tried to SetOutputToNull of the connector (which was an attempt to free resources), and now it seems to work. HAvn't got any of the two exception since this change. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also stick this in a `Try` / `Catch` block and in the `catch` run `SpeakAyncCancelAll`.